# How to set the terminal to "always on top" in elementary OS?

Tags: window-management, gala, pantheon-terminal

I am trying to keep pantheon-terminal always on top. I installed gnome terminal also but I cant find any option to keep always on top.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although disabled by default, you can assign a keyboard shortcut to enable any window to stay on top in Gala. Simply assign your desired key combination to the **Toggle always on Top** option located under *System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Windows.*

[image]