# Why are all elementary specific apps missing the 'Always on top' option?

Tags: applications, window-management, window-manager

I just realized that all elementary apps, unlike all other apps apps, are missing the *Always on top* option (among many others). Right clicking on the top bar in their windows only shows the *Close* option.

This question [How to set the terminal to "always on top" in elementary OS?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1457/how-to-set-the-terminal-to-always-on-top-in-elementary-os) shows a way to by-pass this issue, but I'd like to know if this is by design, and if it is, what is the reasoning behind it?

There does not seem to be any immediate benefit from hiding this (these) option(s), specially since the *Close* option is still there and it is obviously redundant (one can close an app via the X button, via `Planck`, or with the Alt+F4 shortcut).

Comment: It has been done for apps made specifically for elementary os,and this is done by design. Fortunately in Loki this 'limitation' is removed and hopefully, you will be able to see all options in near future.

Comment: @GibreelAbdullah would you mind changing your comment to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been done for apps made specifically for elementary os,and this is done by design. Fortunately in Loki this 'limitation' is removed and you will be able to see all options in near future.

Comment: Thank you. If you have a source for what you stated, please add it.

Comment: @Gabriel I briefly used Loki (by using the elementary daily build in ubuntu 16.04) and there I found this.

Comment: @Gabriel I might install it again in a few days (if i get time), I will post the screenshot then. by the way you have a nice name ;)